# How do I terminate a previous git process that is running in a repository

Tags: git, heroku

I was pushing my app into heroku when I accidentally exited out of my terminal while it was still running. I assumed that meant the process was over so I had to start all over. But when I tried to upload my app into heroku, it said

```
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue
```

I looked up on the internet to see how I could stop the previous process from running and the solution many people recommended was to type this code `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` but when I typed it, I got this error

```
Remove-Item : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Filter -Force.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -f ./.git/index.lock
+    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

What should I do? I don't want to create a new heroku app because I messed up two times already

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with git, but you need to be **really careful** copying commands that you don't understand. "rm -f" just means "delete this file", that's what people are recommending you do, it doesn't matter how. It's a Unix shell command, but you're running Windows PowerShell, which is why you're getting an error. The fact that you didn't know what it did before you ran it should make you really scared.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command `rmdir ./.git/index.lock -force`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because your platform might be different. I was using windows and for me following command works.
Just make sure if you are using windows then there should be backward slashes in address.

```
del "./.git/index.lock"
```